# View textfile in QListWidget, add and remove

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I want to be able to add timestamps to a QListWidget instance and save this to a textfile. As well as view the items already in the textfile so the items are saved after program exit.

The code I have at the moment saves it to the list as I want to, but I do not see the items I added before closing and reopening the program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from datetime import datetime


class feedingTime(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.feedList = QListWidget()
        self.label = QLabel(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),self)
        self.button = QPushButton("Add time")
        self.info = QLabel("Baby was last fed:")

        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.info)
        layout.addWidget(self.feedList)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QTimer(self.label)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
        self.timer.start()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.feedAdd)

    def feedAdd(self):
        self.feedList.addItem(self.label.text())

    def displayTime(self):
        self.label.setText(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = feedingTime()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there and easy way to read list from textfile as well as appending new timestamps when button is pressed? It would also be nice to add a button that removes the "oldest" timestamp when clicked.

Im trying to make a brestfeeding app for my wife :)

PyQt noob here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving data to a `log` has nothing to do with `PyQt`. All you need is basic knowledge of working with I/O in Python. I used simple `log` file which must be located in same directory as the script does (could be improved to something more sophisticated). I implemented also desired `delete` button, however, I'm not sure if I correctly understood meaning of `"oldest" timestamp`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from datetime import datetime

FILENAME = "history.log"

class feedingTime(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.feedList = QListWidget()
        self.label = QLabel(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),self)
        self.button = QPushButton("Add time")
        self.info = QLabel("Baby was last fed:")
        self.buttonDelete = QPushButton("Delete oldest")

        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.info)
        layout.addWidget(self.feedList)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonDelete)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QTimer(self.label)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
        self.timer.start()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.feedAdd)
        self.buttonDelete.clicked.connect(self.deleteOldest)

        self.loadOldData()

    def deleteOldest(self):
        self.feedList.takeItem(self.feedList.count() - 1)
        lines = open(FILENAME).readlines()
        with open(FILENAME, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(lines[1:])

    def feedAdd(self):
        date = self.label.text()
        self.feedList.addItem(date)
        f = open(FILENAME, 'a')
        f.write(date + '\n')
        f.close()
        self.feedList.sortItems(Qt.DescendingOrder) # change to AscendingOrder if want inverted order

    def fillData(self, lines):
        for line in lines:
            self.feedList.addItem(line.rstrip())

    def loadOldData(self):
        try:
            file = open(FILENAME)
            lines = file.readlines()
            self.fillData(lines)
        except IOError:
            print "File" + FILENAME + "not found, skipping..."

    def displayTime(self):
        self.label.setText(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = feedingTime()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and explanation. This was very helpful to me. I'll play around with it some more so I'm able to fully understand what each of the lines you added does. Again. Thank you for the help!